# Do these intervals have the same image under the $e^z$ transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the image of $D_1=\{z \in C: 0 \lt Re(z) \lt \infty, 0 \lt Im(z) \lt \pi\}$ the same as the image of $D_2=\{z \in C: 0 \lt Re(z) \lt \infty, \alpha \lt Im(z) \lt \beta \}$ as $0 \lt \alpha \lt \beta \lt \pi$ under $f(z)=e^z$?

I initially said that $f(D_1)$ is the upper half of the complex plane, excluding the x-axis. $f(D_2)$ is like a section of a circle with infinite radius. Sort of looking like $\lt$ with its vertex located at $(0,0)$, found on the upper half of the complex plane [there must be a name to this shape - I'm not a native English speaker], with one line being at $\alpha$ angle and another with $\beta$ angle.

However, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be arbitrary small, why can't they actually describe the entire upper half of the plane, excluding the x-axis? Or can they?

And I apologize for my vague explanations, I hope they are clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $\alpha$ and $\beta$, there are always points in $D_1 \setminus D_2$. On the other hand, you are correct that
$$ \bigcup_{0<\alpha<\beta<\pi} D_2 = D_1.  $$